# Routing with React Navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, reactjs, react-navigation

I'm creating an app in React Native, and I'm using React Navigation. In the main page, I have an array of services. I want to be able to route to different screens in the app based on the indices of the services. This is a snippet of the code. How do I do that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicator,
  AppRegistry,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import SelectMultiple from './SelectMultiple';
import PackingPage from './PackingPage';

const services = 
['Packing Items in Boxes for Shipping and Moving', 
'Unpacking Boxes', 
'Wrap Furniture for Moving and Shipping',
'Wrap Machinery',
'Loading / Lumper Services',
'Unloading / Lumper Services',
'Custom Crating for Boxes, Furniture and Machinery',
'Palletizing Services for Boxes, Furniture and Machinery',
'Shipping / Moving Service to 2nd location',
'Heat Shrink wrapping',
'Shipping Food in AC trucks',
'Shipping Food in Non AC Truck',
'Shipping Cars']

class PackingApp extends Component{

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: '',
  };

  state = { selectedServices: [] }

  onSelectionsChange = (selectedServices) => {
    this.setState({ selectedServices })
  }
```

I also have this snippet of code for a stack navigator with two screens so far. I'd like to add a screen for each service based on its index. I've tried doing that with an if/else, but I cannot get it to work.

```
const PackingNav = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomePage },
  PackingPage: { screen: PackingPage },
}, 
{
  headerMode: "none"
});
```

Comment: Your array of services is just an array of strings. You need to create one component per screen (or service) and then add this to the StackNavigator like you just did for the two other screens.

Comment: Yes, I have a component for each screen. Each service should correspond to a screen. How do I use the indices of the services elements to route to its corresponding screen?

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to connect your screens in React Navigation to your array of services, you'll need to do that manually:

```
const services = [
   { key:'SomeUniqueIdentifier', name:'Packing Items in Boxes for Shipping and Moving' },
   { key:'AnotherUniqueIdentifier', name:'Unpacking Boxes' },
   ...
];

const PackingNav = StackNavigator({
   Home: { screen:HomePageComponent },
   SomeUniqueIdentifier: { screen:PackingPageComponent },
   AnotherUniqueIdentifier: { screen:UnpackingPageComponent },
   ...
});
```

Then in your `HomePageComponent` (or whichever component you're linking to the services from), you can do something along the lines of:

```
render() {
   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
   let menu = [];
   services.forEach(service => {
      menu.push(<Button
         onPress={() => navigate(service.key)}
         title={service.name}
      />);
   });
   return (
      <View>
         {menu}
      </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I have two more questions. I want to be able to select more than one option and have the options in a different color once selected. For instance, if the packing option is selected, the option will change color and route to the packing page once the next button at the button of the page is pressed. However, if both the packing and unpacking options are selected, the options will route to a single page that stacks up the packing page on top of the unpacking page. If more options are selected, it should do the same thing. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: The on/off states of the selected options is something you'd manage outside of React Navigation. One way to do it would be to have a `selectedOptions` state property on the component that you update whenever an option is toggled (and apply styles based on whether the option is in that `selectedOptions` state property), then have a button at the end that, when tapped, calls React Navigations `navigate()` and passes the list of `selectedOptions` as a parameter (see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions) that can be used to decide which components to render on that page.